# warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Can anyone help me with the signed unsigned mismatch?  It's regarding if my_size

```
void set::add(SET_ITEM_TYPE newItem)
  // post: If newItem is not in this set, newItem is added
  //       and the size of the set increased by +1.

 {
     if (positionOf(newItem) == -1 )
  {

  if(my_size >= my_item.capacity())
  {
    my_capacity = 2 * my_item.capacity();
    my_item.resize( my_capacity );
  }
    my_item[my_size] = newItem;

     my_size++;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error (actually most probably only a warning) is self-explanatory. my_item.capacity() returns an unsigned type and you compare it to a signed type.

Comment: If you want to know what the issues here are, we kinda need to know what the types are. i.e, what's the type of my_size, what's they type of my_item.capacity.

Comment: You want to fix your indentation, too. In fact overall your formatting here is horrendous.

Comment: The cause for the warning is due to arithmetic conversion. If you compare an `int` to an `unsigned int`, the `int` is "converted" to `unsigned int`, this has the effect of making any negative values become positive values, and therefore making a comparison false even when it is mathematically true.

Comment: My guess was that `my_item` is a vector of SET_ITEM_TYPE or something (because `capacity`, `resize` and `operator [](int)`)

Comment: @dreamlax: The `int` is not "promoted" to `unsigned int`. There are no "promotions" between these two types. (4.13/1: "The rank of any  unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding signed integer type.")

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, had my wires crossed.

Comment: @dreamlax: Better now ;)

Comment: yes, I got it.  just lack of sleep.  thanks

Comment: size_t is unsigned, because you cannot have a negative size and "int" is signed, which I assume is what my_size is.

In order to make the comparison, the compiler is going to make a judgement call on how to normalize the numbers. If it changes the signed number to unsigned, it may suddenly become a very large positive number (-1 = 4294967295 or 0xffffffff), if it makes the signed number unsigned, it might become negative.

Some compilers use this for optimizing: `if(i < 0 || i > 10)` can be replaced with `if((unsigned)i > 10)`.

Comment: @kfsone: The compiler doesn't make a judgement call, there is well-defined behaviour for what should happen. If one type is signed, and the other is unsigned, then the signed type is converted to unsigned. It will never make an unsigned number signed, as that is not the behaviour described in the C standard.

Comment: True, sorry for waxing poetic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `my_size` is defined as an `int`, you can fix this by changing its type to `unsigned int`. A size can't be negative; why make it signed?

(`std::vector::size` and the like return unsigned types for a reason)